# Calculate Average Time Duration in PHP from a csv file. Average time seems 0 milisseconds

Tags: php, time, average, intervals

I have a csv file with these values:

```
Iteration, Duration
0,00:00:02.694414
81,00:00:02.790214
82,00:00:02.933225
83,00:00:03.077099
84,00:00:03.220184
85,00:00:03.363437
```

On the second column of it I have a time duration in `H:i:s.ss` format and I need to calculate the average duration: `sum(Duration)/csv_size`

In order to do that I use this function:

```
/**
 * convert a DateTimeIntervalIn milliseconds
 * @return int Time in miliseconds
 */
function intervalInMiliseconds(DateInterval $interval) : float
{
    return ($interval->days*86400 + $interval->h*3600 
           + $interval->i*60 + $interval->s)*1000 + ($interval->f*1000);
}

/**
 * Undocumented function
 *
 * @return int
 */
function calculateAverageTime(string $csvFile)
{
    if ( !file_exists($csvFile) ) {
        throw new Exception('File not found.');
    }

    $file = fopen($csvFile,"r");
    $count=0;
    $duration= new DateTime('00:00');
    $durationCalc= clone $duration;
    while(($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){
        $duration->add( DateInterval::createFromDateString($data[1]));
        $count++;
    }

    if($count == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("No Data In the CSV");
    }

    $duration=$duration->diff($durationCalc);
    $averageSeconds=intervalInMiliseconds($duration)/$count;

    fclose($file);

    return $averageSeconds;
}

$time = calculateAverageTime(__DIR__.'/timestamps.csv');

echo $time;
```

But my question is how I can format a `DateInterval` in miliseconds in order to be able to calculate the average time in miliseconds I get 0, a result that seems no right to me. I expect fractions of milliseconds but not 0 with the data given above.

Therefore do you know how to fix that?

Edit 1:
A quick var_dump shows

```
  var_dump($datetime);
```

Shows failure in parsing my timestapms into DateInterval:

```
class DateInterval#1 (16) {
  public $y =>
  int(0)
  public $m =>
  int(0)
  public $d =>
  int(0)
  public $h =>
  int(0)
  public $i =>
  int(0)
  public $s =>
  int(0)
  public $f =>
  double(0)
  public $weekday =>
  int(0)
  public $weekday_behavior =>
  int(0)
  public $first_last_day_of =>
  int(0)
  public $invert =>
  int(0)
  public $days =>
  bool(false)
  public $special_type =>
  int(0)
  public $special_amount =>
  int(0)
  public $have_weekday_relative =>
  int(0)
  public $have_special_relative =>
  int(0)
}
```

So how DO I convert the timestamp from csv into DateInterval?

Comment: Does it make much sense to try and handle this via DateTime and intervals in the first place …? I’d grab me that `00:00:02.694414` value, split it at the colon, and calculate the according value in seconds from that.

Comment: Somne enties actually are in `00:02:10.586603` as well.

Comment: Yeah, so that is `0 * 60 * 60 + 2 * 60 + 10.586603` seconds then …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing times with milliseconds/microseconds with DateTime can lead to inaccuracies.
I would do it exactly as suggested in the comment by @04FS.

Principle:

```
$durations = [
  "00:00:02.694414",
  "00:00:02.790214",
  "00:00:02.933225",
  "00:00:03.077099",
  "00:00:03.220184",
  "00:00:03.363437"
];

$sum = 0.0;
foreach($durations as $duration){
  list($h,$m,$s) = explode(':',$duration);
  $sum += $h * 3600 + $m * 60 + $s;
}
$avg = $sum/count($durations);
echo $avg;  //3.0130955
```

The function [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) can be used to extract the durations from a 2-dimensional array (csv).